# CSS doesn't render

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc

When I make change at the css file, the result doesn't appears when I run the app (I tried to clean/rebuild the solution but same problem).

**BundleConfig:**

```
...
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
             "~/Content/Index.css",
             "~/Content/Layout.css",
             "~/Content/Login.css"
             ));
```

**Index.cshtml:**

```
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Index";
  Layout = "../Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }
<head>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Index.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

When I check with chrome tool:

[image]

In this image the css is not updated when I change at the code.

Comment: Did it work before and now it's just not updating?

Comment: I think I [found the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137775/css-not-updated-during-debugging-asp-net-mvc-application), tried with Edge and it shows the updated css

Comment: Ctrl + F5 - To refresh and clear cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the browser to use a cached version of your CSS file, a common solution is to append a query string to the end of the file's URL in your HTML. This is a method of cache busting, and is useful for development/testing when you're making lots of changes to your CSS or JS static files.

Here are a couple of quick ways to achieve this:

1. Manually add a query string to the end of the URL, and any time you want the browser to request a new version of the CSS file, just change the value:

```html
<link href="@(Url.Content("~/Content/Index.css") + "?v=1")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

2. Dynamically add a unique query string. This is useful if you want the browser to request a new copy of the CSS file every time:

```html
<link href="@(<Url.Content("~/Content/Index.css") + DateTime.Now().ToString(yyyyMMddHHmmss))" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

3. If you're using ASP.NET Core, use a [tag helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.taghelpers.linktaghelper?view=aspnetcore-2.2), which will automatically append a new version number only when there's a change to the file. You just add a simple attribute:

```html
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Index.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" asp-append-version="true" />
```